# mongoose; 404 when remove object from collection with _id

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, mongoose

I have a strange behavior on a mongoose api who remove object from collection.

i call an the api passing the id as parameter (i checked and the ID exist), 
but what i obtain is a response 404.

**here how i call the api using angular service:**

```
  private deleteInvoice = 'http://localhost:3000/api/elimina_fattura';    

 deleteInvoices(id){
   let headers = new Headers();
   headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   return this.http.post(this.deleteInvoice+'/'+id, {headers: headers})
   .map((response: Response) => response.json())    
 }
```

**here the api defined in mongoose**

```
app.delete('/api/elimina_fattura/:id',(req,res)=>{
Fatture.remove({_id: req.params.id})
.then(()=>{
    res.json({'status':'ok'});
 })
 .catch((err)=>{
    res.json(err);
});
});
```

**here the message when i call the api**

[image]

i have tried to do the same query in robomongo, and seems working

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see on front-end you have mentioned request type POST try changing it to DELETE

```
 deleteInvoices(id){
   let headers = new Headers();
   headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   return this.http.delete(this.deleteInvoice+'/'+id, {headers: headers}) // changed HTTP method
   .map((response: Response) => response.json())    
 }
```